# Alembic: When autogenerating migrations how to ignore database tables by other products

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I am using Alembic to manage migrations for a database. The same database is used by multiple Python packages and each of them have their own migration paths.

How I can tell Alembic to ignore tables from other packages when generating automatic migrations? For example when I run:

```
   alembic -c development.ini revision --autogenerate -m "Initial migration"
```

My migration Python file contains drop tables for other packages (not in the current Alembic env.py):

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('table_from_another_package`)
```

I can manually edit migration file and remove `drop_table()` and `create_table()` entries, but this is manual error prone work. I'd rather avoid generating them in the first place.

Comment: Good question, although probably not such a great design to have multiple  products access the same database. Do you at least use different schemas? Or some naming conventions?  I do not think this is supported out of the box, but if i needed to make it work, i would probably look at the code which is reflecting the database (either `Metadata` or `Engine`) and find a way to overwrite it so that it filters out *no my tables*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Full control over what objects autogenerate considers is [here](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=include_object#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object).

If you are trying to run autogenerate in such a way that it considers only individual MetaData objects at a time you probably want to add customization in your env.py file that takes advantage of the ["X" argument](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=get_x_argument#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.get_x_argument). Use this argument to receive which sub-component you want to work on, and consult that within your `include_object` function to look at just the objects that are relevant to that sub-component.